# Web server pack issue .. Module not found

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am beginner in React.js and tried many tutorials for seting up the environment for React.js!!

first it came

> The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli. Please install
>   'webpack-cli' in addition to webpack itself to use the CLI.
>   -> When using npm: npm install webpack-cli -D
>   -> When using yarn: yarn add webpack-cli -D module.js:472
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Object. (F:\ReactJs\FirstReact\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:65:1)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)

then i run the :

```
npm install webpack-cli
```

and then i get this error below several trying may tutorials

> ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080
>   (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve './src' in 'F:\ReactJs\FirstReact'  @ multi
>   (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080
>   (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src main[2]

Comment: What is your folder structure? Does `src/index.js` exists?

Comment: nope.. there is no src folder just index.js with other files main.js and etc

Comment: That is the problem, webpack is expecting to have a `src/index.js`. You'll have to customize you webpack config to point to where is your entrypoint.

Comment: i have kept it in same folder where all my files are.. as per tutorial

Comment: But the tutorial might be old, or not updated.

Comment: ya it can be possible till when i tried more than 5 tutorials and question was same!!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your webpack.config.js , please check with typo with (module.export). it should (module.exports)